Tcolorbox remove part of box border
So, I want to remove small part of the border in my tcolorbox. Here is an example:

If possible, I'd also like to have a small white outline around "Some title here" as showed in the picture.
The crutial part is that there is no white/ colored box around "Some title here". A possible solution is to have a white box exactly at the border or something, but the point is I want it to look like the picture, for any backgroundcolor and not like it looks in the MWE.
This is what I have (MWE):
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    top=4mm,
    before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm, 
    colback=yellow, colframe=red, % Colors
    colbacktitle=yellow,
    % The titlebox:
    coltitle=red,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3.2cm,yshift=-0.4cm},
    rounded corners,arc=3mm,
    % The "folded paper" in the bottom right corner:
    drop fuzzy shadow, % Shadow
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    boxed title style={
      IfEmptyTF={#1}{interior engine=empty}{},
      frame code={%
        \node[fill=red,font=\bfseries\color{white},anchor=east,rounded corners=1mm] at ([xshift=0.4mm]frame.west) {\textit{Definition \thetcbcounter}};    
      },
    },
    title={\strut #1}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\begin{definition}[Some title here]
    This definition has a title. 
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
    This definition does NOT have a title.
\end{definition}

\end{document}

which produces:

How can I fix this?

You could manually draw the frame, this way your title does not need a background colour:
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{contour}
%\pagecolor{green}


\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    top=4mm,
    before skip=5mm,after skip=2mm, 
    colback=lightgray, 
%    colframe=red, % Colors
%     The titlebox:
    coltitle=red,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3.2cm,yshift=-0.4cm},
    rounded corners,arc=3mm,
    % The "folded paper" in the bottom right corner:
    drop fuzzy shadow, % Shadow
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\subframe}[1]{
  \node[fill=red,font=\bfseries\color{white},anchor=west,rounded corners=2mm] (title) at ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west) {\strut \kvtcb@savedelimiter~\thetcbcounter:};
  \node[anchor=west,font=\bfseries\color{red}] (subtitle) at (title.east) {\strut\contour{white}{#1}};        
  \draw[red,very thick,rounded corners=3mm] (subtitle.east) -- (interior.north east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) --(interior.north west) -- (title.west);
}
\newcommand{\titleframe}{
  \node[fill=red,font=\bfseries\color{white},anchor=west,rounded corners=2mm] (title) at ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west) {\strut \kvtcb@savedelimiter~\thetcbcounter:};
  \draw[red,very thick,rounded corners=3mm] (title.east) -- (interior.north east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) --(interior.north west) -- (title.west);
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{Definition}[1][]{%
  detach title,
  frame hidden,
  IfEmptyTF={#1}{overlay={\titleframe}}{overlay={\subframe{#1}}},
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{Theorem}[1][]{%
  detach title,
  frame hidden,
  IfEmptyTF={#1}{overlay={\titleframe}}{overlay={\subframe{#1}}},
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\begin{Definition}[Homeomorphism]
    This definition has a title. 
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}
    This definition does NOT have a title.
\end{Definition}

\begin{Theorem}[Homeomorphism]
    This definition has a title. 
\end{Theorem}


\end{document}



Thank you! I also added colors as arguments to the functions \titleframe and \subframe so I can more easily switch colors (I want different boxes in different colors). But this is an easy fix from your code.

Here is an answer that is more color flexible, and a little different than @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 's. Thought it might be useful:
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{contour}

\newcommand{\noTitleOption}[2]{%
      \node[fill=#2,font=\bfseries\color{white},anchor=west,rounded corners=2mm] (title) at ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west) {\strut #1 \thetcbcounter:};
      \draw[#2,very thick,rounded corners=3mm] (title.east) -- (interior.north east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) --(interior.north west) -- (title.west) ;
}

\newcommand{\TitleOption}[3]{%
      \node[fill=#3,font=\bfseries\color{white},anchor=west,rounded corners=2mm] (title) at ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west) {\strut #2 \thetcbcounter:};
      \node[anchor=west] (subtitle) at (title.east) {\strut\contour{white}{\textcolor{#3}{\bfseries #1}}};        
      \draw[#3,very thick,rounded corners=3mm] (subtitle.east) -- (interior.north east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west) --(interior.north west) -- (title.west) ;
}


\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{definition}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    top=4mm,
    before skip=7mm,after skip=4mm,
    boxsep=5mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3.2cm,yshift=-0.4cm},
    rounded corners,arc=3mm,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    detach title,
    frame hidden,
    colback=#2!10, 
    coltitle=#2,
  IfEmptyTF={#1}{overlay={\noTitleOption{Definition}{#2}}}
  {overlay={\TitleOption{#1}{Definition}{#2}}},
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{theorem}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    top=4mm,
    before skip=7mm,after skip=4mm,
    boxsep=5mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=3.2cm,yshift=-0.4cm},
    rounded corners,arc=3mm,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    detach title,
    frame hidden,
    colback=brown!10, 
    coltitle=brown,
  IfEmptyTF={#1}{overlay={\noTitleOption{Theorem}{brown}}}
  {overlay={\TitleOption{#1}{Theorem}{brown}}},
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\begin{definition}[This is a definition]{red}
    This definition has a title. 
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{blue}
    This definition does NOT have a title.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}[A theorem here...]
    Hello?
\end{theorem}

\end{document}

Produces:

